# Why the values of a function are not reflecting their values during function call in angularjs?(new to angularjs)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to display a div of comment box section on ng-click of the button invoking the function from controller as defined in the below HTML...picking up the index values from the table and validating the ng-if condition as shown in the code

```
<button class="btn btn-outlined" ng-click="vm.showCommentBox1($parent.$index, $index)">Save All</button>
   <div class="comment-box custom saveAll" ng-if="tableData.template.selectedTowers[towerIndex].baselines[baselineIndex].toBeCommented">               
      <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" ng-click="baseline.toBeSaved = false" title="Close comment box"><span aria-hidden="true">Ã—</span>
              </button>
              <h3 class="panel-title blue-30">Comment</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control bg-white" ng-model="tableData.template.selectedTowers[$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$index].baselines[$index].comment"
                      placeholder="Add your description"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <button ng-click="saveAllRows(tableData.dealName, tower.towerName, baseline, $parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$index, $index, tower.towerGeo, tableData.template.selectedTowers[$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$index].baselines[$index].comment)"
                    class="btn btn-filled btn-xs pull-right">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The function with the arguments are going undefined while the same arguments in different function possess some values

```
 vm.showCommentBox1 = function (towerIndex, baselineIndex) {
  $scope.tableData.template.selectedTowers[towerIndex].baselines[baselineIndex].toBeCommented = true;
  $scope.tableData.template.selectedTowers[towerIndex].baselines[baselineIndex].toBeSaved = true;
  $scope.tableData.template.selectedTowers[towerIndex].baselines[baselineIndex].showPreviousComments = false;
}
```

in the above code towerIndex and baselineIndex are going undefined while the same has some values intended when different functions are invoked

Example:the below function possess the values for both the arguments

```
 vm.enableSaveButton = function (towerIndex, baselineIndex) {
  // console.log("Changed", baseline);
  $scope.tableData.template.selectedTowers[towerIndex].baselines[baselineIndex].toBeCommented = true;
}
```

By,this situation im stuck and im not able pass the ng-if condition true in my HTML so that i can display the comment box.

please,help on this

Thank you

Comment: What is the definition of `vm`?

Comment: var vm = this;@devnull69

Comment: instead of vm as a variable i tried with $scope too...still the arguments go undefined@devnull69

Answer (score 0):

As it was a button outside the table i can't pass the parameters as ($parent.$index,$index) from controllers because only table possess the $index values...it was my bad i didn't notice that at beginning.